# Want to learn techniques of divisibility in polynomial

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

A question from Romania Imo TST
Let $p$ be a prime number and $f\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ given by
$$f(x) = a_{p-1}x^{p-2} + a_{p-2}x^{p-3} + \cdots + a_2x+ a_1 ,$$where $a_i = \left( \tfrac ip\right)$ is the Legendre symbol of $i$ with respect to $p$ (i.e. $a_i=1$ if $ i^{\frac {p-1}2} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $a_i=-1$ otherwise, for all $i=1,2,\ldots,p-1$).

a) Prove that $f(x)$ is divisible with $(x-1)$, but not with $(x-1)^2$ iff $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$;

b) Prove that if $p\equiv 5 \pmod 8$ then $f(x)$ is divisible with $(x-1)^2$ but not with $(x-1)^3$.

I have seen some solutions. They have used some techniques such as checking $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i \left ( \frac{i}{p} \right )$ or using statement like $(x-1) \nmid (xP'(x))'$,
an someone please help me understanding these techniques?

Comment: Do you know the remainder factor theorem? IE $x-1 \mid f(x) $ iff $f(1) = 0 $. There's a corresponding statement for showing $(x-1)^2 \mid f(x)$ iff $ f(1) = f'(1) = 0$. The solutions are just tabulating those values.

Comment: @Calvin Lin, thanks for helping. Can you please help me with part (b)? I know the factor theorem but I am still confused about the divisibility of$(x-1)^2$

Comment: Likewise, $ (x-1)^3 \mid f(x)  $ iff $ f(1) = f'(1) = f''(1) = 0 $, so you just have to evaluate that. Not that in this case, it is sometimes easier to show that $ 0 =  (xf'(x) )' = f''(x) + xf'(x) $ instead of just $f''(x) = 0$, because of the summation.